# Laravel can't post data to controller

Tags: php, laravel

This is my form and I'm trying to send the id and the title of a product to the controller but I have no clue why I got null as a value.

show.blade.php:

```html
<form action="{{ route('cart.store') }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="{{ $product->id }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="product_name" value="{{ $product->title }}">
    <button type="submit" class="ps-btn mb-10">J'encheris <i class="ps-icon-next"></i></button>
</form>
```

web.php:

```
Route::post('/MesEnchers/ajouter', 'CartController@store')->name('cart.store');
```

CartController.php :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    dd($request->id, $request->title);
}
```

[image]

Comment: the input name is not id or title, are product_id and product_name so those are your request keys

Comment: Fix image preview & improve readability

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your variables are `product_id` & `product_name` not `id` & `title`

try

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    dd($request->product_id, $request->product_name);
}
```

Comment: Omg i need to sleep